Compile nano on macOS
I am trying to compile Nano 8.2 on macOS 15.2. The resulted executable fails to support UTF-8 characters. config.log complains.
configure:52785: WARNING:
  *** Insufficient UTF-8 support was detected in your curses
  *** and/or C libraries.  If you want UTF-8 support, please
  *** verify that both your curses library and your C library
  *** were built with wide-character support.

config.status has the following line.
S["LOCALE_EN_UTF8"]="en_US.UTF-8"

I am absolutely certain that UTF-8 works on a macOS Terminal, 'cos University of Washington's Pico 5.09, that comes with the Mac, works just fine with UTF-8. Why can't Apple just keep nano as it were for donkey years? Instead, they switched back to ancient UW Pico! BTW, Nano or Pico, that came/comes with old/new Mac, never works with colour, whereas Linux always does.
I am not a programmer and I can't fix it. Any suggestions are welcome.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/356430

But I don't want to mess with the standard library, that comes with Mac, by hand. Apple does not ship with dpkg. Nonetheless, I am happy install any new things on a local directory in the user space. UTF-8 support is already there, but Nano does not know how to access it.

Consider installing brew and then brew install nano ... brew is a great way to get Unix tools and not have to worry about building and maintaining them yourself. If you don't want to go that route then you'll have to install (and maintain) your own dependent libraries so nano can link against them.

Thanks @par. Is xcode-select the tool for the job? I have no clue.

https://brew.sh/
